# Problems with Abstract Classes and Interfaces in Java

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

I'm pretty sure this might be me being dumb, but I've looked high and low and asked a more experienced friend for help. However, I'm trying to access x and y from my abstract shape class and use them in my interface. However, I'm currently hitting a brick wall. I think that the best option would be to just make them protected and work around that way. Anyway, my question is, under Moveable in its class move, how would I manipulate x and y?

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package C_I;

import java.awt.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Mouse
 */
public abstract class Shape implements Moveable {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Color myColor;
    private Color background;

    public Shape(int tX, int tY, Color tmpColor, Color tmpBackground)
    {
        x = tX;
        y = tY;
        myColor = tmpColor;
        background = tmpBackground;
    }

    public abstract void draw();

    public abstract void clear();

    public abstract void resize(double s);

    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY()
    {
        return y;
    }

    public Color getmyColor()
    {
        return myColor;
    }

    public Color getBackground()
    {
        return background;
    }

    public void setX(int tmpX)
    {
        x = tmpX;
    }

    public void setY(int tmpY)
    {
        y = tmpY;
    }

}

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package C_I;

/**
 *
 * @author Mouse
 */
public interface Moveable{
    void clear();

    public void move(int alphaX, int alphaY)
    {
        setX(getX() + alphaX);
    }

    void draw();

}
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

There is a very basic mistake in your code:

Your `interface` has a method definition. Whereas *"In its most common form, an `interface` is a group of related methods with empty bodies."*. So you can not provide implementation to method in interface.
So you could move the definition of `move()` method from `Moveable` interface to your abstract class `Shape`.

**EDIT:** Here is how you can do it:

```
public abstract class Shape implements Moveable {
    .....
    public void move(int alphaX, int alphaY)
    {
        setX(getX() + alphaX);
    }
}
public interface Moveable{
    void clear();
    public void move(int alphaX, int alphaY);
    void draw();
}
```

Read about interfaces @ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: Afraid I can't do that, the criteria requires that it have a move method in Moveable.

Comment: @user1256211 Is the criterion that the interface itself *implement* the `move` method, or just that the interface specify that implementing concrete classes contain a `move` method? The latter makes perfect sense; the former is very strange.

Comment: According to his UML diagram and very poor directions, its looking like he wants the former.

Comment: Moveable has one method called move that takes two ints as parameters.  You can think of them as delta-x and delta-y.  Your move method does three things (just like resize).  First, it should clear the shape at its current position.  Next it increments/decrements the shape’s current x and y position by an amount delta-x and delta-y respectively.  For example, move(-1, 1) would decrement the shape’s x-position by 1 and increment its y-position by 1.  Finally, it draws the shape at its new position.

Comment: Interfaces _cannot_ have method implementations.  You must have misunderstood something.

Comment: I'm guessing, but according to his UML and those directions he seems to want it in moveable. So I'm just going to do it the way ya'll have brought up and ask him about it later.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you cannot have a method body in an interface.

If you want multiple classes to share an implementation of the `move` method, some basic options are:

1. Make `Moveable` an abstract class instead of an interface
2. Provide a base implementation of `Moveable` called `MoveableBase implements Moveable`, and have `Shape` extend `MoveableBase`